# Find a specific array in ArrayLists in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to make an average calculator, but with actual weighted grades for classes. I made an array list that would store an infinite amount of doubles but I don't know how to find them or use them. I'm new to this and I don't want someone to do it for me, I want them to explain and give examples of how to find it and implement it. Thank you

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Averager{

static ArrayList <Double> array = new ArrayList <Double>();

public static void main (String[] args){


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    double total = 0;
    int grades;
    int score;
    int counter = 0;
    double average;
    String type;

    type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Which averager do you want to use, weighted or normal?");

    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Normal")){

        System.out.println ("How many scores do you want to average?");
        grades = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("What are your scores?");

        while (counter < grades){

            score = input.nextInt();
            total = total + score;
            counter++;
        }

        average = total / grades;
        average = Math.round (average * 100.0) /100.0;
        System.out.println ("The average is " + average);

    }else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase ("Weighted")){

        // this is the part where i need help
        System.out.println ("Enter the weights of the course, type 0 when finished");
        double weight = input.nextDouble();

        while (weight != 0){

            array.add(weight);
            weight = input.nextDouble();
        }

        for (double i : array){       //i was trying to follow a tutorial but this just outputs all of the variable where as i need section for specific ones 

            System.out.println (i);
        }

    }else{

        System.out.println ("Error 101, can't do that yet");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In your mind what is a [weighted average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean), if you only need one value per data point?

Comment: @Andreas I think of weighted average as a persons input average. He inputs as many weight percanteges as he needs that add up to 100 then for each weight, he enters a score which is multiplied by the percent, and in the end, added all up to find his percent or score in the particular class(like school class).

Comment: @Andreas so say i have 5 scores. 2 of those are weighted 80%. 3 of those are weighted 20%. For the 80%, it multiplies the scores he enters by  0.8 and then multiplies the other scores by 0.2 and all of that is added up to get his average in the class

Comment: @Lukyan I'm confused, you said "He inputs as many weight [percentages] as he needs that add up to 100" but your example has 2 80% and 3 20% which would be 220%. Can you please clarify your requirements?

Comment: @D.B., So two of the scores have a weight of 80% and the other 3 have the weight 20% which add up to 100%, but I'm trying to make it so he could enter as many weights and as many scores per weight to find his average in his math class ig. Unless im not understanding the topic of weighted averages because when i go online to any weighted average calc, it tells me to enter weight for each score, whereas i want to make it so the user has to enter scores per weight. Like i said I am very new to this and I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: I understand now, but unfortunately I don't think this type of question is one that belongs on stackoverflow. My advice would be to think about the structure of the data and how the different elements relate to each other. Also consider how you will use the data and whether you need to store it or just use it as it is entered. Take a look at other stack exchange communities to find a better fit for this question as I'm guessing it will be downvoted and closed here.

Comment: @D.B. Ex: History class. 13 scores. 3 diferent weights - 10% 20% 70%. Scores with 10% weight are 100, 100, 100, 95, 50. Scores with 20% are 92, 100, 71. Scores with 70% are 90, 90, 90, 82, 75.So the math would be (((100*0.1)+(100*0.1)+(100*0.1)+(95*0.1)+(50*0.1))/5)+ (((100*0.2)+(92*0.2)+(71*0.2))/3)+(((90*0.7)+(90*0.7)+(90*0.7)+(82*0.7)+(75*0.7))/5) which approximatly is equal to 86 which i do have in the class so it confirsms the math.

Comment: @D.B. Can you answer my question tho plz. I want to find one of the arrays that are stored after being inputed by the user. How can i find it? System.out.println (array[0]); doesnt work, it says i have to use an actual array.

Comment: @D.B., i found it, it is array.get(); thank you for yor help.

Comment: "I don't want someone to **do** ... [but] to explain...": my hat is off to you, friend!  I like to believe there are many more who think like you, but just don't come right out and say it.